# Pexpect does not process output from python script if output is short, but works for longer output

Tags: python, pexpect

So, I am trying to use pexpect to drive some output, and having some weird results.

For testing, I have this script which just prints some stuff for me to expect on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for _ in range(4):
    print('test')
print('<<<canary>>>')
for _ in range(4):
    print('other stuff')
print('<<<end>>>')
```

I then try to expect on this in an ipython session. However, it does not appear to see it at all:

```
In [1]: import pexpect                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: s = pexpect.spawn('./spawn_test.py', logfile=open('outfile.log', 'wb'))                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [3]: s.expect('<<<canary>>>')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOF                                       Traceback (most recent call last)
EOF: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.

In [4]: s.before                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[4]: b''

In [5]: s.buffer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[5]: b''
```

No output at all. However, if I just bump the range up in the original script (say, to 40000 instead of 4), then it works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for _ in range(40000):
    print('test')
print('<<<canary>>>')
for _ in range(40000):
    print('other stuff')
print('<<<end>>>')
```

then

```
In [1]: import pexpect                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: s = pexpect.spawn('./spawn_test.py', logfile=open('outfile.log', 'wb'))                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [3]: s.expect('<<<canary>>>')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[3]: 0 (0x0)

In [4]: s.expect('<<<end>>>')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[4]: 0 (0x0)
```

The odd thing is that even though it works in the second case (which proves that in general the method works), in the first case, there is no output from the script at all - I stepped into the function all the way down to os.read(self.fileno), and it returned nothing. Which doesn't make any sense, so I feel like I am missing something. Also, `s.terminated` changes from `False` to `True` after the expect that throws the EOF; `read()` and `readline()` also return no output in the first case, but work fine in the second case.

This is on OSX, python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is a known issue with pexpect. The solution seems to be to wrap the command with a shell e.g.

```
s = pexpect.spawn('bash -c spawn_test.py')
```

Not ideal, but it did fix the above case.

It feels like there is a different real problem behind this, but this workaround is sufficient.